# Show sort arrow on Ext.grid on page load

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, grid

I have a grid that shows the product id as shown below.

[image]

​​The data is sorted with the product ID but the grid doesn't show the arrow initially. 
If I click on the column then the arrow shows up. How do I make the sort arrows to show immediately on page load as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `colRef.setSortState('ASC')` on column's afterrender listener, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2u7

Comment: ​It worked fine, but Ext sorting it again. Is there any way to tell me not to sort again because the data is sorted.

Comment: Not sure, but you could consider removing the initial sorters from the store so that the data won't get sorted twice on load.

Comment: Looks like it is removed in Ext 5 and not able to find the alternative solution.

Comment: Sort arrow will appear just by setting sorters, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/f28

Comment: ​It worked perfectly. Thanks. But I think it is sorting it on the front end even if data is already sorted.